# How can I create this custom Bottom Navigation on Android

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to create this custom Bottom Navigation. The design is really good but I do not know how to code such a Navigation.

[image]

As you can see, the middle item is the profile pic of the user and the navigation buttons have that custom yellow rounded rectangular as a current page indicator. Any idea how to implement this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View) . 
you have to customize this .

Comment: Here is also one of the option to get above using this : https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

Comment: Uu, didn't know about this library. Looks good, not sure yet how I do the yellow indicator but i'll figure it out. If it still doesn't work ill go ahead the old fashioned way of creating the custom bottom navigation using XML layouts and sticking it at the bottom of the view. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by using library for material design. There are some sites that provides the this type of views you can modified it in some restricted mode.

The sites you can prefer:
[Click here to visit the site](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/)

The below site also helps you..
[bottomAppBar](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-bottomappbar-navigation-with-fab-8b962bb55013)

[Ui Design For Bottom Naviagtion](https://androiduipatterns.com/ui-pattern-evolution-fab-in-bottom-nav-6aaa34b9cc59)