# How to create idling animation for android app button

Tags: android, user-interface, animation, button

Working on android studio to create a testing app with a play button, is there any way to create an animation as shown below when the button is idling?

[image]

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rAIo.png)[image][image]

The animation involves enlarging the padding of the button while fading out the color of the border line. Since I cannot find any related examples online to create this type of button animation, I wonder what is the steps needed to recreate this button in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have to visit this site [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449660/how-can-i-create-this-custom-bottom-navigation-on-android/55449985#55449985). your answer is same as it. Hope will helps you.